# Swift: Cambiar alpha de un botón cuando es pulsado ubicado en un TableView

Tags: swift, botón

En un TableView tengo varios botones por fila, entonces lo que necesito es hacerle ver al usuario cual botón a pulsado antes de abrir el siguiente ViewController.

Lo que se me ha ocurrido es simplemente cambiar el valor del alpha cuando es pulsado, pero no logro que se cambie antes de que se abra la próxima pantalla

Lo he intentado desde dos funciones diferentes, uno se activa con `Touch up inside` y otra `Touch Down` respectivamente.

```
// Touch up inside
@IBAction func showPhotosTaken(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.alpha = 0.5
    delegate?.showPhotosTaken(id_subcategory: id_subcategory, subcategoryName: subcategoryName)
}
// Touch Down
@IBAction func showPhotosTakenTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.alpha = 0.5
}
```

Ambos hace prácticamente lo mismo: al pulsar el botón, nunca se muestra el cambio del alpha solo se muestra la próxima pantalla, pero cuando regreso de esa pantalla noto que el botón a cambiado de alpha, pero no el botón que pulso sino otro de la lista, es decir, si pulso el botón de la tercera fila, se cambia el alpha de la primera, quiero creer que eso es algo que ver con la celda reusable.

El punto es que no cambia antes de mostrar la pantalla. Cabe mencionar que la función al estar los objetos en una celda los tengo delegados por medio de un protocolo, no se si tenga algo que ver.

```
protocol SubcategoryCellDelegate: AnyObject{
    func showPhotosTaken(id_subcategory: Int, subcategoryName: String)
}

class subcategoryCellController: UITableViewCell{
    weak var delegate: SubcategoryCellDelegate?
    @IBOutlet weak var btnShowPhotos: UIButton!
    @IBAction func showPhotosTaken(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.alpha = 0.5
        delegate?.showPhotosTaken(id_subcategory: id_subcategory, subcategoryName: subcategoryName)
    }

class SubcategoryController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SubcategoryCellDelegate {

    func showPhotosTaken(id_subcategory: Int, subcategoryName: String){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SBSPhotos", sender: projectSelected)
    }
}
```

Comment: No veo que uses `sender.tag` para identificar los botones. Cómo los identificas para saber cuál presionaste?

Comment: No uso, creí que con solo `(sender: UIButton)` representa el botón pulsado, en condiciones similares tengo un Switch `(_ sender: UISwitch)` que cuando se activa/desactiva recupero su valor `let isApplicable = sender.isOn` y nunca he necesitado de buscar su correspondiente `tag` no creí que los botones funcionaran diferente.

Comment: En la pregunta mencionas que tienes *varios botones por fila* y colocas dos funciones de tipo `Action`, todos los botones tienen sus `Action` o todos acceden a esas dos funciones?. Si cierras y abres la app, qué pasa con los botones? Debe mostrar los presionados? Si es así no veo que guardes los estados de cada uno para ver si bajas o no el alpha.

Comment: Si, tengo otros botones con su correspondiente `Action` esas funciones son las que he estado probando para ese botón en particular, solo cambia el evento que las lanza `Touch up` y `Touch down` buscando tal vez que lo que necesito es elegir el correcto evento, pero no lo he conseguido, lo de guardar el estado no se si realmente lo necesito, lo único que estoy buscando es que el botón cambie de alguna forma, alpha, imagen, etc. cuando se pulse, como hay tres botones juntos, solo quiero mostrarle al usuario que botón pulso, antes de que se muestre la próxima pantalla.